# Configure cloud-config using Azure Powershell 1.0

Tags: powershell, azure, coreos, etcd

I have spent some significant time getting an Azure PS script starting up a few CoreOS instances.  I have everything working except I have no clue how to get the cloud-config added.

Using the CLI, you can do something like:

```
azure vm create --custom-data=cloud-config.yaml --ssh=22 --ssh-cert=./myCert.pem --no-ssh-password --vm-name=node-1 --connect=coreos-cluster --location="West US" 2b171e93f07c4903bcad35bda10acf22__CoreOS-Stable-522.6.0 core
```

However, the only translation to a powershell script that I could find was adding a Provisioning config.

Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Linux -VM $vm -CustomDataFile cloud-config.yaml

This, won't work because Add-AzureProvisioningConfig is part of the "Azure Services Scripts" and not the new "Resource Manager" scripts.

Does anyone know how to get teh Azure Resource Manager scripts to get cloud-config setup?

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure you're using powershell v1?

Comment: Yes, I installed from powershell gallery, all my other calls are AzureRm